# Create .deb package for a Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, debian, packaging

Is there some sort of an automated way of creating .deb packages from a project.pro file? I tried ubucompilator without much luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to get one of these [packages already using qmake](http://cdbs.ueberalles.net/_qmake.mk.html) with `apt-get source` and `apt-get build-dep`, preferably the simplest, copy its debian/ directory, and tweak it to your needs. [Here is an overview of what the files under debian/ are for.](http://debathena.mit.edu/packaging/)

Comment: apt-get source <package> returns an error for all of the packages in the list. It says 'unable to find a source package'

Comment: Enable the source repos? You can edit /etc/apt/sources.list to add `deb-src` lines to match the `deb` lines, or use `sudo software-properties-gtk` .

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [CPack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPack) which allows you to produce .deb files.  If you are willing to switch to using [CMake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) this process becomes easier.  I believe there are tools that can convert a .pro project to a CMake project.

Comment: No, there are no instrumets converting qmake to cmake